# Latest jquery datepicker, change default date

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I know this question has been asked a lot, but I could find a solution that works for the latest version which by default shows current date on open. Any ideas how to change this to some static date (2011.09.21) ?

I wrote this as a seperate script:

```
<script>
function(){
$(".single-product .i2").datepicker({
     defaultDate: '2011/09/09'
 });
};
</script>
```

But it still loads default date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [defaultDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate) parameter:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    defaultDate: '09/21/2011'
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/vbon9r29/)**

Comment: Where do I put this? See the question, I've wrote my edit.

Comment: Does your datepicker work if you don't set the default date? Can you create a fiddle that has the problem you're experiencing?

Comment: Yes it works without the problem. I will post the code on CodePen so you can see asap.

Comment: I see nothing in your codepen example. You also posted PHP in codepen which it can't take. You should make a minimal example, not just dump all your code there.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.selector').datepicker('setDate', new Date(2011, 8, 21))
```

Comment: See my addition in question please.